# Adding textviews dynamically to relativelayout.

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

While I am adding textviews to relative layout, at the end of first line, the textview is going wrong.

as shown in below:

[image: picture].

here is my code to diplay textviews.

```
public void showkeyword()
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout fl =  (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.key_layout); 
    fl.removeAllViews();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params ;

        //TextView key = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_keyword,null);

i = 0;

   for(String s : alist)
   {   
        TextView textview = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_keyword,null);
        textview.setText(s);
        textview.setId(2000 + i);      

        if (i == 0) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            rlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            textview.setLayoutParams(rlp2);
            fl.addView(textview);

        } else {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           // rlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE);
            rlp2.setMargins(10,0, 10,0);
            rlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textview.getId() - 1);
            textview.setLayoutParams(rlp2);
            fl.addView(textview);  
        }          
       i++;
   }

}
```

I wish to have something like this, sort of a tab implementation:

[image]

Comment: How do you want them to be? They should be aligned vertically?

Comment: @Aniruddha it's like adding tags in stakoverflow. so i want show them in horizontally

Comment: Use LinerarLayout instead of RelativeLayout, it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes @DipakKeshariya is right use LinerarLayout.

Comment: Then why are you not using `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation? Try decreasing the textsize, it will help you out.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya I also did that but facing same problem.

Comment: @chandramohan Please set Vertical Orientation of your LinearLayout.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya then textview coming in next line. i want to add textview right to previous  textview.

Comment: @Aniruddha facing same problem with linearlayout with  horizontal orientation

Comment: Change the `textsize`, `textview.setTextSize(10);`

Comment: @anirudha what if users enters so many keywords.

Comment: @chandramohan it would be better to go for Horizontal scroll view and add text views into it. And please edit your question, add further details a mock up of how you want the view to look?

Comment: Then go with `horizontal scrollview`. What are you going to do with the remaining space? Just asking :D

Comment: @Aniruddha i will try horizontal scrollview. if it exists

Comment: @Kailas  yeah exactly

Comment: @Kailas if u have a solution. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following code will help you out:

Functioning:

contactWrapper  is a linear layout, we go on adding the textviews into these linear layouts one by one and before adding find whether the contactWrapper has space enough to put in the next TextView, if not a new linear layout is created and the textViews are added into it.

Take time analyzing the following code.

```
public void drawLayout() {
    int counter = 0;
    contactWrapperWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    contactWrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
    // contact wrapper is a linear Layout 
    // use LinearLayout contactWrapper = (LinearLayout) mView
    //          .findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayout);
    currCounter = 0;
    currWidth = 0;
    isNewLine = false;

    row[currCounter] = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Iterator it = button.iterator();

    for (int i = 0; i < button.size(); i++) {
        it.next();
        row[currCounter].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        currWidth += Integer
                .parseInt(button.get(i).get("width").toString());
        Log.i("Item width ", "i == "
                + button.get(i).get("width").toString());

        // contactWrapper.getw

        if (isNewLine) {
            if (currWidth < contactWrapperWidth) {
                row[currCounter]
                        .addView((View) button.get(i).get("button"));
                if (!it.hasNext()) {
                    contactWrapper.addView(row[currCounter]);
                } else {
                    if (contactWrapperWidth < (currWidth + Integer
                            .parseInt(button.get(i + 1).get("width")
                                    .toString()))) {
                        isNewLine = true;
                        contactWrapper.addView(row[currCounter]);
                        currCounter += 1;
                        row[currCounter] = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                        currWidth = 0;
                    } else {
                        isNewLine = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                isNewLine = true;
                contactWrapper.addView(row[currCounter]);
                currCounter += 1;
                row[currCounter] = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                currWidth = 0;
            }
        } else {
            if (currWidth < contactWrapperWidth) {
                if (!it.hasNext()) {

                    View view = (View) button.get(i).get("button");
                    row[currCounter].addView((View) button.get(i).get(
                            "button"));
                    contactWrapper.addView(row[currCounter]);
                } else {
                    View view = (View) button.get(i).get("button");

                    row[currCounter].addView((View) button.get(i).get(
                            "button"));
                    if (contactWrapperWidth < (currWidth + Integer
                            .parseInt(button.get(i + 1).get("width")
                                    .toString()))) {
                        isNewLine = true;
                        Logger.show(Log.INFO, "it.hasNext()",
                                "it.hasNext() contactWrapper");
                        contactWrapper.addView(row[currCounter]);
                        currCounter += 1;
                        row[currCounter] = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                        currWidth = 0;
                    } else {
                        isNewLine = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                isNewLine = true;
                contactWrapper.addView(row[currCounter]);
                currCounter += 1;
                row[currCounter] = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                currWidth = 0;
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am able to remove that bug using idea by @kailas

Here I am posting my method:

```
public void showkeyword() {
    int counter = 0;
    int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    final RelativeLayout contactWrapper =  (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.key_layout);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
          150,
          80);

     int i = 0;



    contactWrapper.removeAllViews();
    // contact wrapper is a linear Layout 
    // use LinearLayout contactWrapper = (LinearLayout) mView
    //          .findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayout);
    int currCounter = 0;
    int currWidth = 0;
    boolean isNewLine = false;
    boolean firstLine = true;

    for(final String s : alist)
    {
            TextView textview = new TextView(this);

           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            rlp1.setMargins(7, 5, 7, 0);
            textview.setText(s);
            textview.setId(2000 + i);
            textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            textview.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
            textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             contactWrapper.removeView(v);
             alist.remove(s);
                }

              });

           int width = s.length()*15;
            if((currWidth+width+150)<=screenWidth)
            {
                currWidth += width+10;
                isNewLine = false;
                currCounter++;
            }
            else{
                currWidth = width+14;
                firstLine = false ;
                isNewLine = true;
                currCounter=1;
            }



            if(i==0)
            {     rlp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START);
                  textview.setLayoutParams(rlp1);
                  contactWrapper.addView(textview);
            }
            else if(isNewLine){
                 rlp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
                 rlp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,2000-1+i );
                 textview.setLayoutParams(rlp1);
                 contactWrapper.addView(textview);
            }
            else if(firstLine)
            {
                 rlp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,2000-1+i );
                 textview.setLayoutParams(rlp1);
                 contactWrapper.addView(textview);

            }
            else{

                 rlp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,2000-1+i );
                 rlp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,2000-currCounter+i );
                 textview.setLayoutParams(rlp1);
                 contactWrapper.addView(textview);

            }



            i++;
    }

     buttonparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
     buttonparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE,2000-1+i);
     Button clearbtn = new Button(this);


        clearbtn.setText("clear");
       // clearbtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
       // clearbtn.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        clearbtn.setLayoutParams(buttonparams);
        clearbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         contactWrapper.removeAllViews();
         alist.clear();
            }

          });


   contactWrapper.addView(clearbtn) ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a **LinearLayout** and a **fixed height** (using the dip unit) instead of WRAP_CONTENT

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
rlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
rlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

because the behavior you want is the default behavior.

Put Orientation horinzontal in the relative layout.

Comment: textview overriding previous textview

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all the text you want in one String and then put all this text in only one TextView.

The best way is using StringBuilder to concat the text:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("str1");
sb.append("str2");
```

and then put the string in the textview
    textview.setText(sb.toString());

Comment: actually i want implement onclick listener to each textview.