# Create Tag Cloud

Tags: android, tag-cloud

I need to create a basic **Tag Cloud**. My aim is to add multiple **TextView**(*Tags*) that automatically fits themselves in a new line if the number exceeds the device width. (*Like Instagram*).

Right now when the *width* of the **layout containing** (**TextView**)*tags* exceeds the (**device width**) the TextView(s) at the end *wraps itself*.
[image: the TextView at the last gets distorted]

I tried using *RelativeLayout* but i am unable to figure out the logic.
I viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055289/adding-textviews-dynamically-to-relativelayout) post but if there is a better or simply a cleaner solution.

Thanks for your precious time.

It is not necessary that the result looks like Instagram.
[image: what i want to achieve]

Comment: You should use so-called Flow layout, for example look at this https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cleaner solution is to write your own custom ViewGroup class. Find the sample below.

For a complete descriptive explanation visit, [How to Create Custom Layout in Android by Extending ViewGroup Class](https://stacktips.com/articles/how-to-create-custom-layout-in-android-by-extending-viewgroup-class).

```
public class TagLayout extends ViewGroup {

    public TagLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TagLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TagLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int count = getChildCount();
        int curWidth, curHeight, curLeft, curTop, maxHeight;

        //get the available size of child view
        final int childLeft = this.getPaddingLeft();
        final int childTop = this.getPaddingTop();

        final int childRight = this.getMeasuredWidth() - this.getPaddingRight();
        final int childBottom = this.getMeasuredHeight() - this.getPaddingBottom();

        final int childWidth = childRight - childLeft;
        final int childHeight = childBottom - childTop;

        maxHeight = 0;
        curLeft = childLeft;
        curTop = childTop;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == GONE)
                return;

            //Get the maximum size of the child
            child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
            curWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            curHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            //wrap is reach to the end
            if (curLeft + curWidth >= childRight) {
                curLeft = childLeft;
                curTop += maxHeight;
                maxHeight = 0;
            }
            //do the layout
            child.layout(curLeft, curTop, curLeft + curWidth, curTop + curHeight);
            //store the max height
            if (maxHeight < curHeight)
                maxHeight = curHeight;
            curLeft += curWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

To use the TagLayout, you can add it to your activity/fragment layout declaration.
**main_activity.xml**

```
<com.javatechig.taglayout.TagLayout
    android:id="@+id/tagLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now we can have a custom view to allow some level of customization for each tag item layout.

**tag_layout.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tagTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#a000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

**MainActivity.java**
Finally, from activity class you can add the tag items as follows.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TagLayout tagLayout = (TagLayout) findViewById(R.id.tagLayout);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        String tag;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            tag = "#tag" + i;
            View tagView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_layout, null, false);

            TextView tagTextView = (TextView) tagView.findViewById(R.id.tagTextView);
            tagTextView.setText(tag);
            tagLayout.addView(tagView);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT is not working for the height. The Layout occupies all the space. Can you help me how to wrap the height of this layout. I am using this inside a ScrollView with other elements and when i use wrap_content it doesn't show up where as defining a fix height to the layout works fine

Comment: Alternatively instead of  extending ViewGroup class, you can extend it from LinearLayout.  Eg: public class TagLayout extends LinearLaoyut. In this case you don't need to  override onMeasure() method.

Comment: @harsh_v I have the same issue with `layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 3):

I believe the solution above always consider the whole screen width, so if the developer sets `android:layout_width` parameter for example it won't respect its value or even parent's margin and padding values.

I've fixed it as follows:

```
private int mScreenWidth = 0;
private int mAvailableWidth = -1;

public TagLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {

    Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    Point deviceSize = new Point();
    display.getSize(deviceSize);

    mScreenWidth = deviceSize.x;
}

private void calculateAvailableWidth() {

    if(getLayoutParams() != null && getLayoutParams().width > 0) {
        mAvailableWidth = getLayoutParams().width;
        return;
    }

    mAvailableWidth = mScreenWidth;

    ViewGroup parent = this;

    while(parent != null) {

        mAvailableWidth -= parent.getPaddingLeft() + parent.getPaddingRight();

        if(parent.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)parent.getLayoutParams();
            mAvailableWidth -= layoutParams.leftMargin + layoutParams.rightMargin;
        }

        if(parent.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)
            parent = (ViewGroup)parent.getParent();
        else
            parent = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int count = getChildCount();
    int currentRowWidth = 0;
    int currentRowHeight = 0;
    int maxItemWidth = 0;
    int maxWidth = 0;
    int maxHeight = 0;

    if(mAvailableWidth == -1)
        calculateAvailableWidth();

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);

        if(child.getVisibility() == GONE)
            continue;

        try {
            measureChildWithMargins(child, widthMeasureSpec, 0, heightMeasureSpec, 0);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }

        int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth() + child.getPaddingRight() + child.getPaddingLeft();
        int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight() + child.getPaddingTop() + child.getPaddingBottom();

        maxItemWidth = Math.max(maxItemWidth, childWidth);

        if(currentRowWidth + childWidth < mAvailableWidth) {
            currentRowWidth += childWidth;
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, currentRowWidth);
            currentRowHeight = Math.max(currentRowHeight, childHeight);
        }
        else {
            currentRowWidth = childWidth;
            maxHeight += currentRowHeight;
        }
    }

    if(getLayoutParams().width == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
        mAvailableWidth = maxItemWidth;
        maxWidth = maxItemWidth;
    }

    maxHeight += currentRowHeight + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
    setMeasuredDimension(maxWidth, maxHeight);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    int count = getChildCount();

    int currentLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    int currentTop = getPaddingTop();
    int currentRight;
    int currentBottom;

    int parentWidth = this.getPaddingRight() - this.getPaddingLeft() + right;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        View child = getChildAt(i);

        if(child.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            return;

        int currentWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth() + child.getPaddingRight() + child.getPaddingLeft();
        int currentHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight() + child.getPaddingBottom() + child.getPaddingTop();

        if(currentLeft + currentWidth > parentWidth) {
            currentLeft = getPaddingLeft();
            currentTop += currentHeight;
        }

        currentBottom = currentTop + currentHeight;
        currentRight = currentLeft + currentWidth;

        child.layout(currentLeft, currentTop, currentRight, currentBottom);

        currentLeft += currentWidth;
    }
}
```

This way you are able to set `android:layout_width="250dp"` and get a result like this:

[image]

Set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and get a result like this:

[image]

Or event use `android:layout_width="wrap_content` and get a result like this:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good, but plese fix issure with margins of entire views: margins doesn't work. But paddings works.

Comment: And what about center align?